# Unable to console.log HTML that my method inserts into DOM

Tags: javascript, class, clock

I'm making a simple clock app that displays the current time as a way of practicing my JS in combination with HTML & CSS (I'm quite new to coding).

My code works fine, but I'm confused about an unexpected result I got when experimenting. I created a class, instantiated it, and then tried to print the inner HTML that my display() method was inserting into a pre-existing div (id="time").

See below:

```js
class Clock {
  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date;
    this.day = this.date.getDate();
    this.secs = this.date.getSeconds();
    this.mins = this.date.getMinutes();
    this.hours = this.date.getHours();
  }

  update(increment) {
    this.secs += increment;
    if (this.secs >= 60) {
      this.secs = this.secs - 60;
      this.mins++;
    }
    if (this.mins >= 60) {
      this.mins = 0;
      this.hours++;
    }
    if (this.hours >= 24) {
      this.hours = 0;
    }
  }
  display() {
    this.update(1);
    let HMS = [this.hours, this.mins, this.secs].map(item => item < 10 ? `0${item}` : item);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = `${HMS[0]} : ${HMS[1]} : ${HMS[2]}`;
  }
  run() {
    setInterval(this.display.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}


// TESTING

let clock = new Clock; // Create new clock instance
clock.run(); // Clock is running

let time = document.getElementById('time'); // Retrieving element that contains the time

console.log(time.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Gives empty string! Why does it not log the HTML I inserted in my display() method?

As above, I don't understand why the HTML that's inserted into my 'time' div as part of the display() method isn't recognized when I console.log it. I feel there's a concept that I'm not grasping in this example, and I can't figure out what it is.

Could someone please help explain it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` does not fire immediately, it will only start firing after the first delay (1 second).

As such at the moment your `console.log` fires before there is anything within the time div.

One way around this is to call `this.display` and then set the `setInterval`.

### Example to demonstrate the current problem

In this example I have added some text inside the time div, you will see when you run the example that text displays for a second and is also logged to the console.

I then log the time div contents 1.5 seconds later and it then shows the current time.

```js
class Clock {
  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date;
    this.day = this.date.getDate();
    this.secs = this.date.getSeconds();
    this.mins = this.date.getMinutes();
    this.hours = this.date.getHours();
  }

  update(increment) {
    this.secs += increment;
    if (this.secs >= 60) {
      this.secs = this.secs - 60;
      this.mins++;
    }
    if (this.mins >= 60) {
      this.mins = 0;
      this.hours++;
    }
    if (this.hours >= 24) {
      this.hours = 0;
    }
  }
  display() {
    this.update(1);
    let HMS = [this.hours, this.mins, this.secs].map(item => item < 10 ? `0${item}` : item);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = `${HMS[0]} : ${HMS[1]} : ${HMS[2]}`;
  }
  run() {
    setInterval(this.display.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}


// TESTING

let clock = new Clock; // Create new clock instance
clock.run(); // Clock is running

let time = document.getElementById('time'); // Retrieving element that contains the time

console.log(time.innerHTML);

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(time.innerHTML);
}, 1500);
```

```html
<div id="time">Not Updated Yet</div>
```

### Example to demonstrate for to fix the issue

In this example all I do is call the `display()` function immediately within your `run` function and then set up the `setInterval`. This way the time is set immediately and so can be logged to the console.

```js
class Clock {
  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date;
    this.day = this.date.getDate();
    this.secs = this.date.getSeconds();
    this.mins = this.date.getMinutes();
    this.hours = this.date.getHours();
  }

  update(increment) {
    this.secs += increment;
    if (this.secs >= 60) {
      this.secs = this.secs - 60;
      this.mins++;
    }
    if (this.mins >= 60) {
      this.mins = 0;
      this.hours++;
    }
    if (this.hours >= 24) {
      this.hours = 0;
    }
  }
  display() {
    this.update(1);
    let HMS = [this.hours, this.mins, this.secs].map(item => item < 10 ? `0${item}` : item);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = `${HMS[0]} : ${HMS[1]} : ${HMS[2]}`;
  }
  run() {
    this.display();
    setInterval(this.display.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}


// TESTING

let clock = new Clock; // Create new clock instance
clock.run(); // Clock is running

let time = document.getElementById('time'); // Retrieving element that contains the time

console.log(time.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Clock {
  constructor() {
    this.date = new Date;
    this.day = this.date.getDate();
    this.secs = this.date.getSeconds();
    this.mins = this.date.getMinutes();
    this.hours = this.date.getHours();
  }

  update(increment) {
    this.secs += increment;
    if (this.secs >= 60) {
      this.secs = this.secs - 60;
      this.mins++;
    }
    if (this.mins >= 60) {
      this.mins = 0;
      this.hours++;
    }
    if (this.hours >= 24) {
      this.hours = 0;
    }
  }
  display() {
    this.update(1);
    let HMS = [this.hours, this.mins, this.secs].map(item => item < 10 ? `0${item}` : item);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = `${HMS[0]} : ${HMS[1]} : ${HMS[2]}`;
  }
  run() {
    setInterval(this.display.bind(this), 1000);
  }
}


// TESTING

let clock = new Clock; // Create new clock instance
clock.run(); // Clock is running

let time = document.getElementById('time'); // Retrieving element that contains the time

console.log(time);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```